# Unity don`t reading OnMouseDown and UP in place, where collider and trigger intersected. How can i fix this?

Tags: unity-game-engine

There place red lined where script must read a clicks. In other place of sprite its working. (sorry about my bad english)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90AqO.png)

Comment: the OnMouseDown is not detected is because the ladybug's Collider is blocking it (ladybug's Collider is infront of the  leaf)

Comment: How to do so that thay started working together?

Answer (score 0):

try to change the Z axis of the Ladybug so that it's in front of the leaf

Comment: Its not working, probably becouse its unity2d

Comment: unity2d still uses z index, are the elements inside of canvas or not?

Comment: its not canvas, its sprites